# Get all records from a Ref Cursor in a Package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'd like to fetch each row when I call the following function:

```
CpuReporting.getgridusage(300)
```

This function was provided in a CpuReporting package. It has:

```
Function GetGridUsage(minutes_Input in Number) Return CurGridUsage;
Type CurGridUsage is Ref Cursor Return RecGridUsage;
Type RecGridUsage is Record (ConfigId Number,
                           Phase VarChar2(400),
                           Environment VarChar2(400),
                           SessionStartTime Date,
```

I've browsed the GetGridUsage function in PL/SQL Developer, it has two parameters: (Result) REF CURSOR and MINUSTES_INPUT IN NUMBER

I want to be able to fetch all the rows and since I haven't worked with Ref Cursor before, I'm really interested in knowing how will you going to write the PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `CpuReporting` is the package name, you'd want something like

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor CpuReporting.CurGridUsage;
  l_rec    CpuReporting.RecGridUsage;
BEGIN
  l_cursor := CpuReporting.getGridUsage( 300 );
  LOOP
    FETCH l_cursor INTO l_rec;
    EXIT WHEN l_cursor%notfound;

    -- Do something with l_rec.  As an example, print the Environment
    dbms_output.put_line( l_rec.Environment );
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE l_cursor;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the output of the function in PL/SQL you can do this

```
var r refcursor;
exec :r := CpuReporting.getgridusage(300);
print r;
```