# How to run PL/SQL Statement in Ruby Using DBI Connection

Tags: ruby, oracle, plsql, dbi

I'd like to run a simple PL/SQL to test if it is possible to print the standard output.

The PL/SQL block should output: "The total number is: 157"

I run the following Ruby script and it didn't print anything. Would you please advise.

```
require 'dbi'

dbh = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:hr','hr','hr')
dbh.do("BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE; END;")
db_read_str = <<-EOS
declare
  c number;
begin
  select count(*) into c
  from exo_user where sys_logon like 'uk%';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The total number is: ' || c);
end;
EOS

rs = dbh.prepare(db_read_str)
rs.execute
dbh.select_all(db_read_str) do |row|
  p row
end

rs.finish
```

**Looks like going on this route can be difficult. Let me explain what I need and please advise what should I do. I need to manipulate some data to produce a report. The data I have got can be calling a CpuReporting.getgridusage(300) function. The program needs to be written in Ruby.**
also see: [Get all records from a Ref Cursor in a Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793201/get-all-records-from-a-ref-cursor-in-a-package)

Comment: Hm, I don't think `dbms_output` is for producing output on environments other than SQL*Plus. [`The package is typically used for debugging, or for displaying messages and reports to SQL*DBA or SQL*Plus`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#CIHBFFDB)

Comment: "In a separate PL/SQL procedure or anonymous block, you can display the buffered information by calling the GET_LINE Procedure and GET_LINES Procedure." So you can read from the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer. But that doesn't solve your problem. Anyway, DBMS_OUTPUT should not be used in this case. Make a function that returns the value and print it with Ruby.